# shopify_theme with listen enhancements v0.0.7 stalling

Tags: shopify, listen

I am heavily dependent on the most excellent Thor based CLI tool shopify_theme. It was recently improved by Shopify with a switch to Listen from FSSM and seems to work fine.

I was using it yesterday and experienced some glitches though. It seems the **theme watch** command loses synchronization with changes to files. I am not sure what triggers the problem. One thing I do often is use Finder to drag drop new files into assets, and I expect to see the watch command upload those new assets. Instead, nothing appears on stdout. Editing files after also fail to trigger uploads.

I cannot say for certain that the **Listen** object is the culprit, but it is troubling in that now I have to watch the watcher terminal window to see if it is actually watching. Anyone else use this gem and experience the glitch???

Comment: check what version of listen you have installed/using. is latest?

Comment: gem which shows: listen-0.5.3